# Backtracking in Go to find all paths in Directed Acyclic Graph, problem assigning paths to a solution slice (Leetcode 797)

Tags: algorithm, go, backtracking

I am attempting [Leetcode 747](https://leetcode.com/problems/all-paths-from-source-to-target/) in Go. The problem summary:

> Given a directed acyclic graph (DAG) of n nodes labeled from 0 to n -
> 1, find all possible paths from node 0 to node n - 1, and return them
> in any order.
>
> The graph is given as follows: graph[i] is a list of all nodes you can
> visit from node i (i.e., there is a directed edge from node i to node
> graph[i][j]).

This is my solution so far:

```golang
func allPathsSourceTarget(graph [][]int) [][]int {
    allSolutions := [][]int{}
    target := len(graph) - 1

    isSolution := func(current int) bool {
        return current == target
    }

    processSolution := func(solution []int) {
        allSolutions = append(allSolutions, solution)
    }

    var backtrack func(currentPath []int)

    backtrack = func(a []int) {
        currentNode := a[len(a)-1]
        if isSolution(currentNode) {
            processSolution(a)
        } else {
            candidates := graph[currentNode]
            for _, c := range candidates {
                a = append(a, c)
                backtrack(a)
                a = a[:len(a)-1]
            }
        }
    }

    backtrack([]int{0})

    return allSolutions
}
```

It passes 7/30 inputs but then fails on this one `[[4,3,1],[3,2,4],[3],[4],[]]`. The expected output for which is `[[0,4],[0,3,4],[0,1,3,4],[0,1,2,3,4],[0,1,4]]`.

I believe the problem is how I am appending each result to the `allSolutions` slice. If I log the solution that comes in each time, it's what is expected, but it seems to then mutate the solutions already added.

If I add logs to the `allSolutions` func, for the above input, this is the output:

```
Solution:
[0 4]
New allSolutions:
[[0 4]]
Solution:
[0 3 4]
New allSolutions:
[[0 3] [0 3 4]]
Solution:
[0 1 3 4]
New allSolutions:
[[0 1] [0 3 4] [0 1 3 4]]
Solution:
[0 1 2 3 4]
New allSolutions:
[[0 1] [0 3 4] [0 1 2 3] [0 1 2 3 4]]
Solution:
[0 1 4]
New allSolutions:
[[0 1] [0 3 4] [0 1 4 3] [0 1 2 3 4] [0 1 4]]
```

I am interested in knowing why this is happening. Is it related to modifying the variable from a higher scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`processSolution` should copy its argument. Otherwise, `backtrack` continues to mutate the slice that it passes in, which results in the corruption that you're seeing.

Comment: Great, thanks! I used the [copy](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#copy) function and that solved my problem.